# HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden while create upload session

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to upload a file to Sharepoint. I Got the Accesstoken based on the client id and tenant id given by the application and able to do it.

```
'client_id='||'xxxx'||'&scope='||'https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default'||'&client_secret='||'xxxxxx'||'&grant_type='||'client_credentials'
```

Token as follows :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Based on the token i am trying to create an upload session and it is saying http1.1 403 forbidden. I have the known site id and Drive (Item id).

[image: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxx/drive/items/xxxxx:/test123.xml':/createUploadSession]

```
HTTPResponseHeader X-Original-HTTP-Status-Line:CHARACTER:HTTP/1.1 403 
Forbidden X-Original-HTTP-Status-Code:INTEGER:403 Cache-Control:CHARACTER:private 
Content-Type:CHARACTER:application/json request-id:CHARACTER:1f6e2c51-5061-41c0-be0d-ee38a2c2a533 
client-request-id:CHARACTER:1f6e2c51-5061-41c0-be0d-ee38a2c2a533 x-ms-ags-
diagnostic:CHARACTER:{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_11"}} 
Strict-Transport-Security:CHARACTER:max-age=31536000 
Date:CHARACTER:Fri, 19 Jun 2020 17:23:53 GMT Content-Length:CHARACTER:256
```

Application had given permissions to Sites.readwrite.All provided admin consent as well. Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the full listing of scopes from the decoded access token?

Comment: @GavinB, Thanks for checking on it. Below is the requested information:

Comment: @GavinB,@GavinB, Thanks for checking on it. Below is the requested information.I had executed acquired tokens based on two options one with  Scope as https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default  and it returned tenant_region_scope":"NA" 
,"tenant_region_scope":"NA","tid":"xxxx","uti":"x
-------------------------------------
Also I have tried other with actual share point site https%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com%2F.default as scope (second option) and nothing returned for scope
,"roles":["Sites.ReadWrite.All"],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a couple of things here:
To use the Microsoft Graph APIs to create an upload session to write a file to SharePoint using the site/library as a drive with an app only permission (client_credentials) you need to request the at least the `Sites.ReadWriteAll` scope for the Microsoft Graph resource `https://graph.microsoft.com`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0
Instead of requesting the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` scope try using 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.ReadWriteAll`

Comment: Thanks GavinB, Precisely you are spot on !! Administratot had given the below permissions roles":["Sites.ReadWrite.All","Files.ReadWrite.All"], and i am able to upload the file now. Thanks for your help !!